# How do I pass the value of drop down with form submit?

Tags: javascript, php, html

I have these 2 drop downs:
[image]

I have to provide values of Select Item drop down based on the value chosen in the Select Category drop down.

This is my PHP for Select Category drop down:

```
<form>
...
    <select name="category" id="category" value="category" class="form-control ddplaceholder" style="width:220px;font-size:18px;font-family:Roboto;" onclick="document.form.submit();">
                 <option value="" disabled selected>Select Category</option>
...
<input type="submit" name="submit" style="width:20%;padding:15px;" value="Update"</input>
...</form>
```

But nothing is happening. How do I do it?

Comment: http://www.appelsiini.net/projects/chained

Comment: provide more info about "nothing is happening". Also your `input` tag is not properly closed

Comment: The value selected in category drop down isn't passed.

Answer (score 0):

Try `onchange` instead of `onclick`

```
<form>
...
    <select name="category" id="category" value="category" class="form-control ddplaceholder" style="width:220px;font-size:18px;font-family:Roboto;" onchange="document.forms[0].submit();">
                 <option value="" disabled selected>Select Category</option>
...
<input type="submit" name="submit" style="width:20%;padding:15px;" value="Update"</input>
...</form>
```

Two more things you should notice

1. > `onchange="document.form.submit();"` this will not work because
   >   `document` doesn't have a property `form` it is `forms` so you should
   >   use `onchange="document.forms[0].submit();"`
2. > You have named your `submit button` as `submit` which will prevent the
   >   `form` from `submitting` because `submit` is a `javascript function` so
   >   rename your submit button to something else.

Comment: Hey, changing the name of submit button worked. I'm now able to fetch the category value selected by the user. But now there's another problem. I want the selected value of category drop down to be retained even after the page is refreshed on selecting the value. How do I do that?

Comment: You can pass the value in querystring and on page load get the value from querystring and select in dropdown

Comment: How do I initialize a query string? I've never used it.

Comment: Look at url at end it is `appened` with  `?` after that whatever comes is called querystring.

Comment: So how do I initialize it?

Comment: There is a better approach use `html5` cache like `localStorage.setItem("selectedval", yourval);` and to get value `var val = localStorage.getItem("selectedval")`

Answer (score 0):

If you dont have many possible values for your dropdowns, you can use plain old javascript for that purpose. See this http://jsfiddle.net/mplungjan/65Q9L/, but it requires all values to be loaded at once on the page load like this:

```
var stateObject = {
    "California": {
        "Monterey": ["Salinas", "Gonzales"],
        "Alameda": ["Oakland", "Berkeley"]
    },
    "Oregon": {
        "Douglas": ["Roseburg", "Winston"],
        "Jackson": ["Medford", "Jacksonville"]
    }
}
```

Comment: Understand, then go for user2181397 answer based on ajax

Answer (score 0):

`document.form.submit()`; will submit the form which is not the requirement.

Instead you need to make an [**ajax**](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) call with the selected value from first dropdown and the response will be use to build the options of second dropdown.

use [**change**](https://api.jquery.com/change/) which will trigger on change of option

```
$('category').on('change', function (e) {
    var optionSelected = $("option:selected", this);
    var valueSelected = this.value; // will give value of selected option

   $.ajax({
     url:"someUrl", // this url will return response from backend
     // other methods
     success:function(response){
        //use this response to build the second dropdown
      }
    })



});
```

Comment: How do I build the HTML drop down inside javascript? I don't know how to use it. Plz let me know.   ` <select name="name_update" value="name_update" >
                   <option value="" disabled selected>Select Item</option>
            <?php
            $category_find="";
            if(!empty($_POST['category']))
            {
                $category_find=$_POST['category'];
                
            } 
            $sth = $conn->prepare('Select name From item where category=:category');
            $sth->execute(array(':category'=>$category_find));
         `

Comment: $data = $sth->fetchAll();   
            foreach ($data as $row ){
                if($row['name']!="")
             echo ' <option id=\"ItemName\" name=\"ItemName\" value="' .$row['name']. '">'.$row['name'].'</option>';
            }
            ?> </select>